# Корректно ли называть setter мутатором?

Tags: java, setter

Читая Блоха "Эффективная java" столкнулся с определением Мутатор. Если я правильно понял контекст то это обыкновенный setter ("сеттер") и это своеобразная неточность перевода. Но часто можно встретить, что используется определение именно сеттера.

В итоге - это неточность перевода или я что то не верно понял?
Или же все таки Мутатор - это любой метод меняющий внутреннее состояние объекта и его переменные, соотвественно сеттер - это просто вид мутатора?

Comment: Посоветуйте где можно подробнее ознакомиться с множеством мутаторов (какие они бывают и т.д.). Не хочется иметь лингвистические пробелы в определниях

Comment: С сожалением должен сказать, что похоже ввел вас в заблуждение. Ksenia совершенно права - mutator и setter - синонимы. Век живи - век учись.

Comment: @rjhdby понял, спасибо. Так даже проще)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В данном случае мутатор и сеттер просто синонимы.